# NSCoding - Save the parent attribute causes a crash

Tags: arrays, swift, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver

When using `NSCoding` or `NSKeyedArchiver` for a parent-child relationship; I am unable to set a reference in the child to the parent as it will end up crashing on the Swift Playground.

I want to have a reference in my `Child` class to my `Parent` class.

But it will end up crashing on the Playground when it comes to loading the data back into memory.

```
class Parent: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var children:[Child] = [Child]()

    init(children:[Child]?) {
        if let childrenList = children {
            self.children = childrenList
        }
    }

    public convenience required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let children = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "children") as! [Child]

        self.init(children: children)
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(children, forKey:"children")
    }

}

class Child: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var parent: Parent

    init(parent:Parent) {
        self.parent = parent
    }

    public convenience required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let parent = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "parent") as! Parent

        self.init(parent: parent)
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(parent, forKey:"parent")
    }
}

var parent1 = Parent.init(children: nil)
var parent2 = Parent.init(children: nil)
var child1 = Child.init(parent: parent1)
var child2 = Child.init(parent: parent2)
parent1.children.append(child1)
parent2.children.append(child2)

let parents = [parent1, parent2]


let manager = FileManager.default
let url = manager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first! as URL
let writeFile: URL = url.appendingPathComponent("sample.data")

print ("Attempting to write to: \(writeFile.path)")


NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(parents, toFile: writeFile.path)

// Crash occurs here.
if let parentData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: writeFile.path) as? [Parent] {
    for p in parentData {
        print ("\(p.children.count)")
    }
}
```

In the `Child` class I want a reference to the parent; so that in future I can do tests or filtering on child objects with certain parents.

However, I always get this crash on the Playground:

> Playground execution aborted: error: Execution was interrupted,
>   reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10). The process has been
>   left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to
>   return to the state before expression evaluation.

It seems to crash on the reference to the parent object.

How do I ensure that NSCoding will save my parent attribute in a child object?

Many thanks

---

Edit: Refactored code

This refactored code appears to work, although I do not know if I've done it right.

```
class Parent: NSObject, NSCoding {
    private (set) var children:[Child] = [Child]()

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    public convenience required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let children = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "children") as! [Child]

        self.init()
        self.createChildren(children: children)
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(children, forKey:"children")
    }

    func addChild(child:Child) {
        child.parent = self
        self.children.append(child)
    }

    private func createChildren(children:[Child]) {
        for child:Child in children {
            self.addChild(child: child)
        }
    }
}

class Child: NSObject, NSCoding {
    weak var parent: Parent?

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    public convenience required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init()
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    }
}

var parent1 = Parent.init()
var parent2 = Parent.init()
var child1 = Child.init()
var child2 = Child.init()
parent1.addChild(child: child1)
parent2.addChild(child: child2)
let parents = [parent1, parent2]


let manager = FileManager.default
let url = manager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first! as URL
let writeFile: URL = url.appendingPathComponent("sample.data")

print ("Attempting to write to: \(writeFile.path)")


NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(parents, toFile: writeFile.path)


if let parentData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: writeFile.path) as? [Parent] {
    for p in parentData {
        print ("\(p.children.count)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think through what is currently happening in your code. You archive a parent. The parent archives its children. Each of those children then tries to archive its parent. Then each of those parents try to archive its children. This cycle then goes on and on until it goes "boom".

You have a few issues:

1. In your `Child` class, the `parent` property needs to be `weak`. Otherwise you have a reference cycle and lots of memory issues.
2. Your `Child` class should make no attempt to encode/decode its parent.
3. Your `Parent` class should set itself as the parent of each child when the parent is decoded.

Your crash is caused by violating issue 2.

As a side note to issue 3, I would refactor your code. Do not pass a parent when creating a child. And do not directly expose the `children` array in your `Parent` class. I would add methods to the `Parent` class for adding and obtaining children. The method to add children should set the `parent` property of each child added to it.

Comment: Okay, I will try to refactor my code.  The advice of making references to parent a weak reference is a good one. I had not thought of that.    I will try to refactor my code and see where I am after that

Comment: i've refactored my code.  (1) Made the `children` a private (set) var, 
(2) child objects do not encode/decode parent
(3) function to add children, which sets the parent property
(4) parent property is `weak`

The code no longer crashes, although I do not know if I did everything right.